# Build Stability Plugin Teamcity SonarQube

Tags: build, widget, teamcity, sonarqube, metrics

Is there a plugin similar to build stability plugin in SonarQube to report on build metrics? I am using a Teamcity continuous integration server?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such a plugin in the SonarQube ecosystem.